# Passing ID to Controller using Ajax - Error 404 in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, http-status-code-404

I am new to Laravel.
Trying to Pass ID from View to Controller but getting Error

> POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/getbuffaloidformonitor 404 (Not Found)

This is my View BuffaloMonitor :

```js
$(document).on('click', '.viewmonitormodal', function() {
    var modal_data = $(this).data('info').split(',');
    $('#viewbuffaloID').val(modal_data[1]);
    var buffaloid = document.getElementById('viewbuffaloID').value// get buffalo id from textbox to get data for that ID
    alert(buffaloid);
    //alert(data);
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            method : "POST",
            url: "/getbuffaloidformonitor",
            data: {
                '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                'id': buffaloid,
            },        
            success : function(response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

This is BuffalomonitorCOntroller :

```php
public function getbuffaloidformonitor(Request $req) {
    $data = buffalodata::find($req->id);
    alert(data);
    $id = $req('data');
    return $id;
}
```

This Is Route

```
Route::post('/getbuffaloidformonitor/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\BuffalomonitorController@getbuffaloidformonitor')->name('getbuffaloidformonitor');
```

Comment: In my opinion "getbuffaloidformonitor" should be a GET request. in that case you have to add the parameter to the URL, not in the data of your request, and add it as a parameter in your `public function getbuffaloidformonitor(Request $req, $id) ` (Or change the name and url for the route). Naming is very important for easy maintenance in the future

Answer (score 1):

Your post route has `{id}` but it's not necessary. This is what you need `Route::post('/getbuffaloidformonitor','App\Http\Controllers\BuffalomonitorController@getbuffaloidformonitor')->name('getbuffaloidformonitor');`

Comment: Correct, and upvoted, however a route getbuffaloidformonitor sounds more like a GET route to me. correct naming is very important in my opinion

Comment: You are right, for me too ;)

Answer (score 0):

pass **id** to the link http://127.0.0.1:8000/getbuffaloidformonitor

as you write the route

```
   Route::post('/getbuffaloidformonitor/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\BuffalomonitorController@getbuffaloidformonitor')->name('getbuffaloidformonitor');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just pass id by routes Params, so the URL must like this

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/getbuffaloidformonitor/yourbuffaloid

You need to change URL.

```
$.ajax({
   method : "POST",
   url: "/getbuffaloidformonitor/" + buffaloid,
   data: {
      '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
      //'id': buffaloid, remove this line
   },        
   success : function(response) {
      alert(response);
   }
});
```

If you use this script in you blade template just use

```
const url = '{{ route("getbuffaloidformonitor",":id") }}'

$.ajax({
    method : "POST",
    url: url.replace(':id',buffaloid),
    data: {
       '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
       //'id': buffaloid, remove this line
    },        
    success : function(response) {
       alert(response);
    }
});
```

If your routes {id} is optional just

```
Route::post('/getbuffaloidformonitor/{id?}','App\Http\Controllers\BuffalomonitorController@getbuffaloidformonitor')->name('getbuffaloidformonitor');
```

with question on your id route you can use both by pass id by route params or you can pass id by data post.

In controller

```
public function getbuffaloidformonitor(Request $req, $id = null)
{
    // id is get from route params
    $getId = $req->get('id') // this one get from data post.
}
```

Comment: thanks for Quick Reply..... But now getting error    ...                                                                                               POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/getbuffaloidformonitor/Buffalo-02 404 (Not Found)..... I am new to Laravel and coding.... Thanks in Advance

Comment: What's route do you use? In routes directory has separate routes, Which file did you define route above?